# Zend Framework 2 Authentication without DbTable check

Tags: php, session, authentication, zend-framework2

i'm trying to make a Zend 2 classical Authentication, without using a DbTable check.

I'll explain better

- I've a custom method authenticate() that is able to authenticate a user (independently from Zend Auth).
- I've made a custom class that extends Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session
- Now i want to save data into session with something like this:

  ```
  $authService->getStorage()->write($this);
  ```

The problem is using that code when in the next page call i perform:

```
if($authService->hasIdentity())
```

it response false.

So, how can i do to save identity using custom authentication? i think i can implement Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface but i don't known exacly how...

any help is appreciated,
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an adapter like so:

```
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\Result as AuthResult;

class MyAdapter implements AdapterInterface
{

    /**
     * @return \Zend\Authentication\Result
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        /* Return if can't find user */
        return new AuthResult(AuthResult::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND, null);
        /* Return if success, second parameter is the identity, e.g user. */
        return new AuthResult(AuthResult::SUCCESS, $identity);
        /* Return if user found, but credentials were invalid */
        return new AuthResult(AuthResult::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID, null);
    }
}
```

You can use this adapter with the ZF2 AuthenticationService like so:

```
$auth_service = new \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService();
/* Where $myAdapter is a instance of the MyAdapter class above */
$auth_service->setAdapter($myAdapter);
```